# Tensorflow LinearRegressor not converging

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, regression

I'm attempting to do a toy linear regression in Python with TensorFlow, using the pre-built estimator tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor instead of building my own estimator. 
The inputs I'm using are real-valued numbers between 0 and 1, and the outputs are just 3*inputs. TensorFlow seems to fit the data (no errors raised), but the outputs have no correlation to what they should be.

I'm not sure I'm getting the predictions done correctly- the documentation for the predict() function is pretty sparse.

Any ideas for how to improve the fitting?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Defining data set
x = np.random.rand(200)
y = 3.0*x
data = pd.DataFrame({'X':x, 'Y':y})
training_data = data[50:]
test_data= data[:50]

COLUMNS = ['Y','X']
FEATURES = ['X']
LABELS = 'Y'

#Wrapper function for the inputs of LinearRegressor
def get_input_fn(data_set, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
  return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
      x=pd.DataFrame(data_set[FEATURES]),
      y=pd.Series(data_set[LABELS]),
      num_epochs=num_epochs,
      shuffle=shuffle)


feature_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in FEATURES]
regressor = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols)
regressor.fit(input_fn=get_input_fn(test_data), steps=100)

results = regressor.predict(input_fn=get_input_fn(test_data, 
num_epochs=1))
predictions = list(itertools.islice(results, 50))

#Visualizing the results
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[8,8])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(test_data[LABELS], predictions)

ax.set_xlabel('Actual')
ax.set_ylabel('Predicted')
plt.show()
```

[Scatter plot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGI8o.png)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer, answering here for posterity- 
my input function to LinearRegressor had shuffle=True set as an argument, and my predict() call did not set shuffle=False. So the outputs were shuffled around, making them look like they didn't converge!